# How to save combobox value on button click

Tags: vb.net, button, combobox

I have 2 comboboxes which I'm trying to use as dropdown lists and I want to be able to click a button to save the selected values of those comboboxes without using global variables, but I can't access their values in the button.click event. And I'm not really sure how to use tags to do it. (I tried, it didn't work, not sure if that's because I missed something or they have no initial value).

How would I be able to reference the contents of these comboboxes so that i can save their values?

Here is my code:

```
        Private Sub Options_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim WindowChoice, ScreenChoice As New ComboBox
    Dim SaveChanges As New Button
    ScreenSizes(0) = "640x360"
    ScreenSizes(1) = "960x540"
    ScreenSizes(2) = "1024x576"
    ScreenSizes(3) = "1280x720"
    ScreenSizes(4) = "1600x900"
    ScreenSizes(5) = "1920x1080"
    WindowChoice.Items.Add("Windowed")
    WindowChoice.Items.Add("Fullscreen")
    For i As Integer = 0 To ScreenSizes.length - 1
        ScreenChoice.Items.Add(ScreenSizes(i))
    Next

    MainMenu.AddObject(SaveChanges, _
                       (Me.Width / 2 + SaveChanges.Width / 2), _
                       (Me.Height / 2 + 4 * SaveChanges.Height), _
                       "Save Changes", _
                       Me) 'These add the object at a specified postion

    MainMenu.AddObject(WindowChoice, _
                       (Me.Width / 2 + WindowChoice.Width / 2), _
                       (Me.Height / 2 - 2 * WindowChoice.Height), _
                       "", _
                       Me)

    MainMenu.AddObject(ScreenChoice, _
                       (Me.Width / 2 + ScreenChoice.Width / 2), _
                       (Me.Height / 2), _
                       "", _
                       Me)

    AddHandler SaveChanges.Click, AddressOf SaveChanges_click
    SaveChanges.Tag = Str(WindowChoice.SelectedItem(0)) & Str(ScreenChoice.SelectedItem) 'this line currently does not work, but even if it were able to assign a value, it would only do so before an option has been selected
End Sub

Private Sub SaveChanges_click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    If sender.Tag(0) = "W" Then
        MainMenu.Windowed = True
    ElseIf sender.Tag(0) = "F" Then
        MainMenu.Windowed = False
    End If
    Dim res As String = ""
    For i As Integer = 1 To sender.tag.length - 1
        res &= sender.tag(i)
    Next
    MainMenu.Res = res
End Sub
```

Comment: ComboBox1.SelectedValue should be able to access the the selected value for the ComboBox1 control. If a value doesn't exist though it should throw a Null exception when you run it. The only other issue could be with the access modifier of the control compared to the button.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work when used in my button.click event, the button and comboboxes have been added through code during form_load, not design, if that makes a difference.

Comment: Would be worth updating your question with the code that creates the controls and the code that tries to access the combo box control.

Comment: ok, ive updated with the code.

Comment: Using the Tag is no better than a form level variable.  Also your code wont compile under Option Strict - `System.Object` does not have a Tag property

Comment: OK so at that point nobody has selected an item hence when `SelectedItem` is `Nothing`. You will need `ScreenChoice.Items(0)` to access the first item in the list if that's what you're after or maybe come at it a different way.

Comment: that different way is sort of what im after, i know this can be solved using global variables, but id like to avoid them if at all possible. i just want to be able to reference `SelectedItem` in `SaveChanges_click`

Comment: [**My.Settings Object**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/saa62613.aspx).

Comment: When it comes to controls it should be ok to declare them in the global space.  All the controls you added through the designer are there anyway.  Plus this will solve your problem in the easiest way possible.

Comment: Also learn about [Scope in Visual Basic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t0wsc67.aspx) you cannot declare a control (or anything) inside  a method or event handler and be able to reference it outside that method.  Variables and objects exist only where they are declared.

Comment: ok, thanks, global it is. I'll take a look at scope too.

Comment: There is nothing inherently evil about global variables, but there is a difference between a class/form level variable and one that is truly global.